# show DIV once selected option PASS from drop down menu

Tags: javascript

I would like to create simple drop down with options and one of the will be PASS then show DIV once selected option PASS from drop down menu, for other options DIV will be closed

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('mfi_4_a_i').onchange = function(){
    if (this.value == 'PASS') {
        document.getElementById('sdd').style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getELementById('sdd').style.display = "none";
    }
};
</script>
<select id="test" name="test" onChange="changetextbox();">
    <option value="PASS">PASS</option>
    <option>No</option>
    <option>No, but planning in future</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="test" id="sdd" />
```

Comment: What's your actual problem where you are stuck?

Comment: well, it's just doesn't work :(

Comment: Show us more code, like the part where you generate the dropdown and the one with your divs

Comment: @user974435 Remove `'` from `true` and `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order

```
<select id="test" name="test" onChange="changetextbox();">
    <option value="PASS">PASS</option>
    <option>No</option>
    <option>No, but planning in future</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="test" id="sdd" />

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('mfi_4_a_i').onchange = function(){
    if (this.value == 'PASS') {
        document.getElementById('sdd').style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getELementById('sdd').style.display = "none";
    }
};
</script>
```

You need to ensure that when the JavaScript runs the DOM elements are ready ....

**Note** your `id` attributes do not match either ..`mfi_4_a_i` in JavaScript vs `test` in HTML and you should either write a function `changetextbox` or write `getElementById('blah').onchange = function() {` not both ...

```
<select id="test" name="test">
    <option value="PASS">PASS</option>
    <option>No</option>
    <option>No, but planning in future</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="test" id="sdd" />

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('test').onchange = function(){
    if (this.value == 'PASS') {
        document.getElementById('sdd').style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('sdd').style.display = "none";
    }
};
</script>
```

[Working example here](http://jsbin.com/iyucul/edit#javascript,html,live)

**Another Note** you had

```
document.getELementById('sdd').style.display = "none";
```

this should be

```
document.getElementById('sdd').style.display = "none";
```

I changed the case of the `L` in Element

Comment: have fixed that and still doesn't work

Comment: @user974435 see my update at the bottom ... working fine for me (note you also had a mistake in the `document.getElementById('sdd').display = "none"` line ... your `getElementById` had an uppercase `L` in Element

Answer (score 0):

You'd want something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('ID_OF_DROPDOWN').onchange = function(){
    if (this.value == 'PASS') {
        document.getElementById('ID_OF_DIV').style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getELementById('ID_OF_DIV').style.display = "none";
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: it doesn't work, have eidted main question