# display div if option is selected in jquery with css selectors

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a drop down list with 4 surface type options. The fist option is the default and is a shown div with input boxes for user to enter dimensions, the rest of the other options are hidden on page load via css. Currently, if I select a non-rectangle option, it does not hide the default div and show the hidden div. 
Here's the html:

```
    <div class="calc-wrap">
    <h3>Soil and Mulch</h3>
    <label for="surface">Type of surface:</label>

   <select id="surface" name="surface" onchange="selected_surface('calc_id', this.value)">
    <option value="_rect" selected="selected">Rectangle</option>
    <option value="_circle">Circle</option>
    <option value="_ring">Ring</option>
    <option value="_triangle">Triangle</option>
</select>

    <div class="user-inputs">
    <div id="rectangle">

        <div class="calc-input">
            <label for="length"><strong>Length</strong>(ft):</label>
            <input id="length" name="length" text="text" />
        </div><!--end of calc-input-->

        <div class="calc-input">
            <label for="width"><strong>Width</strong> (ft):</label>
            <input id="width" name="width" type="text" />
        </div><!--end of calc-input-->
    </div><!--end of rectangle-->

    <div class="hidden_field" id="circle">
        <div class="calc-input">
            <label for="radius"><strong>Radius</strong>(ft.):</label>
            <input id="radius" name="radius" type="text" />
        </div><!--end of calc-input-->
    </div><!--end of circle-->

    <div class="hidden_field" id="ring">
        <div class="calc-input">
            <label for="in_diameter"><strong>Inside Diameter</strong>(ft.):</label>
            <input id="in_diameter" name="indiameter" type="text" />
        </div><!--end of calc-input-->
        <div class="calc-input">
            <label for="ex_diameter"><strong>Outer Diameter</strong>(ft.):</label>
            <input id="ex_diameter" name="exdiameter" type="text" />
        </div><!--end of calc-input-->
</div><!--end of ring-->

    <div class="hidden_field" id="triangle">
            <div class="calc-input">
                <label for="base"><strong>Base</strong>(ft.):</label>
                <input id="base" name="base" type="text" />
            </div><!--end of calc-input-->
            <div class="calc-input">
                <label for="height"><strong>Height</strong>(ft.):</label>
                <input id="height" name="height" type="text" />
            </div><!--end of calc-input-->
        </div><!--end of triangle-->


        <div class="calc-input" id="soil_mulch_depth">
            <label for="soil_mulch_depth"><strong>Depth</strong>(inches):</label>
            <input id="soil_mulch_depth" name="depth" type="text" />
        </div><!--end of soil_mulch_depth-->
</div><!--end user_inputs-->

        <div class="results">
            <div class="calc-result">
                <label><strong>Volume</strong>(yards&sup3;)</label>
                <div class="result-value" id="soil_mulch_result"></div>
            </div><!--end calc-result-->
            <br>
            <div class="calc-result">
                <label><strong>Number of bags</strong>:</label>
                <div class="result-value" id="soil_bags_needed">0</div>
                <label>of soil</label>
                <input class="soil_parts" id="bags_soil" name="bags_soil" type="hidden" value="25" />
            </div><!--end result-value-->
            <br>
            <div class="calc-result">
                <label><strong>Number of bags:</strong>

                </label>
                <div class="result-value" id="mulch_bags_needed">0</div><!--end result-value-->
                <label>of mulch</label>
                <input class="mulch_parts" id="bags_mulch" name="bags_mulch" type="hidden" value="9" />
            </div>
            <br>
            <button class="calc-submit" onclick="bulk_calculate(" soil_mulch ",0)">Calculate</button>
```

Here's the css:

```
.hidden_field {
    display:none;
}

.user-inputs {
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;
}
.results {
    float:left;
}
.calc-wrap {
   margin:30px 0;
   line-height:1;
}
.calc-wrap select {
   margin:0;
}
.calc-wrap input {
   margin:0 0 9px;
   font-family:arial;
   width:100px;
}
.calc-submit {
   clear:both;
   display:block;
}
.calc-wrap label {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:170px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.calc-result label {
    width:auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.result-value {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.calc-wrap h3 {
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #8dc63f;
    font-family:'Tahoma', sans-serif;

}
```

Here's the jquery:

```
    function selected_surface(calc_id, show_id){
    $ = jQuery;
    $('#' + calc_id + '_rect').css('display', 'none');
    $('#' + calc_id + '_circle').css('display', 'none');
    $('#' + calc_id + '_ring').css('display', 'none');
    $('#' + calc_id + '_triangle').css('display', 'none');
    $('#' + calc_id + '_manual').css('display', 'none');
    $('#' + calc_id + show_id).css('display', 'block');
    }
```

see my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rnle99/8nKFg/5/

I've tried looking at previous questions such as:

[show DIV once selected option PASS from drop down menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502335/show-div-once-selected-option-pass-from-drop-down-menu)

[Display div if option is selected in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325548/display-div-if-option-is-selected-in-jquery)

Comment: `onchange="selected_surface('calc_id', this.value)"` Are you sure you want to pass the string `'calc_id'` to your function every time?

Comment: The IDs of the DIVS are rectangle, ring, circle etc. Yet you are referencing them by names calc_id_rect, calc_id_ring, calc_id_circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple issues with your code...

Mainly, the values being passed from options when the change event fires don't match up to the IDs of the hidden containers.

Here's a fiddle which works. I've simplified the selector logic, changes the html slightly and have everything executing on document ready. Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/adamfullen/2Kk38/

HTML

```
<div class="calc-wrap">
     <h3>Soil and Mulch</h3>
     <label for="surface">Type of surface:</label>

    <select id="surface" name="surface" onchange="">
        <option value="rectangle" selected="selected">Rectangle</option>
        <option value="circle">Circle</option>
        <option value="ring">Ring</option>
        <option value="triangle">Triangle</option>
    </select>

    <div class="user-inputs">
        <div class="hidden_field" id="rectangle">

            <div class="calc-input">
                <label for="length"><strong>Length</strong>(ft):</label>
                <input id="length" name="length" text="text" />
            </div><!--end of calc-input-->

            <div class="calc-input">
                <label for="width"><strong>Width</strong> (ft):</label>
                <input id="width" name="width" type="text" />
            </div><!--end of calc-input-->
        </div><!--end of rectangle-->

        <div class="hidden_field" id="circle">
            <div class="calc-input">
                <label for="radius"><strong>Radius</strong>(ft.):</label>
                <input id="radius" name="radius" type="text" />
            </div><!--end of calc-input-->
        </div><!--end of circle-->

        <div class="hidden_field" id="ring">
            <div class="calc-input">
                <label for="in_diameter"><strong>Inside Diameter</strong>(ft.):</label>
                <input id="in_diameter" name="indiameter" type="text" />
            </div><!--end of calc-input-->
            <div class="calc-input">
                <label for="ex_diameter"><strong>Outer Diameter</strong>(ft.):</label>
                <input id="ex_diameter" name="exdiameter" type="text" />
            </div><!--end of calc-input-->
    </div><!--end of ring-->

        <div class="hidden_field" id="triangle">
                <div class="calc-input">
                    <label for="base"><strong>Base</strong>(ft.):</label>
                    <input id="base" name="base" type="text" />
                </div><!--end of calc-input-->
                <div class="calc-input">
                    <label for="height"><strong>Height</strong>(ft.):</label>
                    <input id="height" name="height" type="text" />
                </div><!--end of calc-input-->
            </div><!--end of triangle-->


            <div class="calc-input" id="soil_mulch_depth">
                <label for="soil_mulch_depth"><strong>Depth</strong>(inches):</label>
                <input id="soil_mulch_depth" name="depth" type="text" />
            </div><!--end of soil_mulch_depth-->
    </div><!--end user_inputs-->

            <div class="results">
                <div class="calc-result">
                    <label><strong>Volume</strong>(yards&sup3;)</label>
                    <div class="result-value" id="soil_mulch_result"></div>
                </div><!--end calc-result-->
                <br>
                <div class="calc-result">
                    <label><strong>Number of bags</strong>:</label>
                    <div class="result-value" id="soil_bags_needed">0</div>
                    <label>of soil</label>
                    <input class="soil_parts" id="bags_soil" name="bags_soil" type="hidden" value="25" />
                </div><!--end result-value-->
                <br>
                <div class="calc-result">
                    <label><strong>Number of bags:</strong>

                    </label>
                    <div class="result-value" id="mulch_bags_needed">0</div><!--end result-value-->
                    <label>of mulch</label>
                    <input class="mulch_parts" id="bags_mulch" name="bags_mulch" type="hidden" value="9" />
                </div>
                <br>
                <button class="calc-submit" onclick="bulk_calculate(" soil_mulch ",0)">Calculate</button>
```

JavaScript

```
function selected_surface(calc_id, show_id){
    var $ = jQuery;
    $('.hidden_field').hide();
    $('#'+show_id).show();
}

$(function(){
    $('#surface').on("change", function(e){
        var show_id = this.value;
        selected_surface('calc_id', show_id);        
    });

    $('#rectangle').show();

});
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who took the time to look at my code. All your questions helped me learned the mistakes I made mostly variables, id's and passing variables. Adam Fullen's answer helped me see that there are better ways of coding.

Comment: TJ answer works perfectly too. I see the function name selected surface in the html and in the script but where did the elm var come from? I'll need a tutorial on passing variables to functions. thnks!

Answer (score 1):

- first of of you're passing *calc_id* `onchange="selected_surface('calc_id', this.value)` i've no idea what that is.
- i've changed the `<option>` values to `rect`, `circle` etc for simplicity.
- i've added `rect` id for the div for rectangle, which was missing.
- i've added `.shape` class to all divs for each shape to access them together.

  ```
    function selected_surface(elm){
      var divId= $(elm).val();
      $('.shape').hide(); // hide all  other shapes
      $('#'+divId).css('display','block'); // show the selected shape
    }
  ```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/8nKFg/24/)